# How to implement simple progress bar in Xamarin PCL?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin forms application and in portable project I would like to have progress bar that looks like this:

[image]

So I would like to have progress bar as yellow line. Progress is defined in Page's ViewModel:

```cs
private int _progress;
public int Progress
{
    get { return _progress; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _progress, value); }
}
```

and it is int value between 0 and 100. On image Progress is 60. How can I implement progress bar in xaml?

Comment: XF contains a built in ProgressBar control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default progress bar in xamarin. It supports MVVM binding so that you can set the upload progress easily. Or else you can use custom progress bar. for ex:http://www.itlec.com/2017/05/advanced-progressbar-real.html

Comment: As I have seen, progress bar has 3 colors: background color, part that is done and part that is not done. Is it possible to set those 3 colors on Advanced progress bar?

Comment: For changing the progress bar color you have to use bindableproperty. Refer thread:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28894/progressbar-color-in-xamarin-forms If you want the progress bar same as the image you posted, try to add a overlay at bottom with controls-boxview,labels,progressbar